# appengine create two modules using same war

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a 2 modules in a java appengine project (one for front-end and one for back-end).

I want to duplicate the back-end module without duplicating the code.
How can I create a new module that uses the same war of the backend module ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can symlink the file(s) (or directories) to be shared inside the respective modules. The deployment utilities know how to replace the symlinks with the actual content of the files/directories they point to.

Comment: Thank you for you response :) but there is a pom which defines the module name and the dependencies so i cannot symlink this pom because each modue should have the same pom but with different module name

Comment: Symlinking is just the technique of sharing - for files/dirs for which sharing *makes sense*. But while some files could be *technically* shared across modules, it might not make sense to do so - the module config files are examples of such files, as you observed.